# How can I define which delimiter the data loader should use when run by command line

Tags: data-loader

Does someone know how define which delimiter the data loader should use when it is executed by command line? I am using version 38.
The GUI has an option for defining allowed CSVs delimitters, but I cannot find that there is a parameter for this using the datalaoder trough command line.

The source files I am loading are delimited by tab and has values containing commas. This makes the dataloader fails since it interprets both as column separation.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your values in double quotes?

Comment: that would work but is not at option in our case

Answer (score 0):

it seems that old Dataloader versions have this option disabled.
You could clone the source code and rebuild your own dataloader version with this feature enabled:

https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader

I have just built my own version and it has this options enabled in the gui.

[image]

Comment: I would rather not build my own version as this will require maintenance and prevent us from updating to newer releases.

Answer (score 0):

Submitted an idea for this at Salesforce Ideas https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E59hQAC